# Select the Audio inside same div and play without using id

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

How can I play audio on button click inside same div using javascript without element id? I want to display the default html player with just a play button. Refer to picture
[image]

```js
var audiofile = document.querySelectorAll('div[class$="audio-clip"]');

audiofile.forEach(function(item) {
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.className = 'btn';
  btn.textContent = "Click to Listen";
  btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        item.find('audio').play();
    })
  item.appendChild(btn);
});
```

```html
<div class="audio-clip">
<audio preload="none" controls="">
<source src="https://staging.buellairhorns.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Buell-Duplex-Air-Horn-Buell-Airhorns.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<button class="btn" type="button">Click to Listen</button></div>
```

Comment: Try Replacing  `item.find('audio').play();` with  `item.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play();`

Comment: Posted a working snippet

Answer (score 0):

```js
var audiofile = document.querySelectorAll('div[class$="audio-clip"]');

audiofile.forEach(function(item) {
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.className = 'btn';
  btn.textContent = "Click to Listen";
  btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        item.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play();
    })
  item.appendChild(btn);
});
```

```html
<div class="audio-clip">
<audio preload="none" controls="">
<source src="https://staging.buellairhorns.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Buell-Duplex-Air-Horn-Buell-Airhorns.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<button class="btn" type="button">Click to Listen</button></div>
```